# one code part in many class files

Tags: java, android

I have an android app with many class files.
in each class i have a code, which is exactly the same.

Is it possible to put this code in a separate file / class and include this in all other class files?

I am talking about this code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_one:
            // Do something 
            break;

        case R.id.nav_two:
            // Do something
            break;

        case R.id.nav_three:
            // Do something
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: yes you can do that, just declare your code and import the class and you its methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Abstract Activity class that extends that method as example:

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onNavigationItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_one:
            // Do something 
            break;

        case R.id.nav_two:
            // Do something
            break;

        case R.id.nav_three:
            // Do something
            break;

        default:
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Then extend your current activities instead of AppCompatActivity (or whatever your Class is) then call super of this method as such:

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onNavigationItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's for do you override it if it doesn't change base behavior?

Comment: Orkun's right. But you don't need to override it. Just derive your Activities from AbstractActivity and it will be fine. Also, you can use just one Activity, but change Fragments in it, using Fragments API.

Comment: Well what I wrote about MainActivity is pretty much it is default state after you extend it with AbstractActivity. I just have wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create base class for all your similar classes? I suppose you have this code in activities. Create NavigationActivityBase class, implement this logic and inherit from it.

Comment: class YourActivity extends NavigationActivityBase { }